# What the intention of this code?(Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

Could somebody tell me the intention of the code below:

```
def factor(a): 
    d=2 
    while (d<=(a/2)): 
        if((a/d)*d==a):
            return ((a/d),d)
        d=d+1 
    return(a,1)
```

I think it uses the binary search, am I right?

Comment: @Ed Cottrell: Could you please tell me the intention of this code?

Comment: I wasn't answering this question; I just fixed the formatting. In any case, Yangfan gave a very nice and correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you plug in numbers and see what the result is? No, this is not a binary search. As the function name indicated, it returns the 2 factors of a number.
say:

```
a,b = factor(10) // a will be 5, b will be 2
```